# flume uuid interceptor for spoolDir events

Tags: hadoop, flume, flume-ng

I am trying to add a UUID for every event in my file when it is pushed to HDFS using flume.

I used the following UUID interceptor:

```
agentTest.sources.sampleDirSource.interceptors = uuidInterceptor
agentTest.sources.sampleDirSource.interceptors.uuidInterceptor.type = org.apache.flume.sink.solr.morphline.UUIDInterceptor$Builder
agentTest.sources.sampleDirSource.interceptors.uuidInterceptor.headerName = id
agentTest.sources.sampleDirSource.interceptors.uuidInterceptor.preserveExisting = true
agentTest.sources.sampleDirSource.interceptors.uuidInterceptor.prefix = "flume_"
```

BUT I don't see any result in my file.
I know I can use the {id} field in the header but from the documentation I was expecting to get a new field add to every log record.

> [This interceptor sets a universally unique identifier on all events that are intercepted](https://flume.apache.org/FlumeUserGuide.html)

Did I miss something?